# Primefaces poll interval to hide dialog not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 5.1. In my Page download button press get records from database to write xls file after to download file.Because large file take long time to download that time I  just shown dialog box for user known waiting time.When downloadaction complete to hide dialog box and show download option.(i.e)dialog box hide to browser taken certain minutes show download options.

**user.xhtml**

```
<p:commandButton value="Download" action="#{user.downloadFile}" onClick="PF('pollWidget').start();"/>

<p:poll id="poll" widgetVar="pollWidget"  interval="10" oncomplete="if(#{user.pollStop}){PF('DialogId').hide();}"
update="dialogId" stop="#{user.pollStop}" autoStart="false"/>

<p:dialog id="DialogId" widgetVar="DialogId" modal="true">
<p:graphicImage url="#{user.progressImage}"/>
</p:dialog>
```

**user.java**

```
public void downloadfile()
{
downloadApplication(currentUser,CurrentToList);
pollStop=true
if(pollStop==true)
{
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance.execute("PF('DialogId').hide();");
}
}
```

My doubt download action complete before dialog box hide to taken certain minutes to download options shown.If I need to change any options poll and also anyother replace options(any component) of poll in primefaces.

Comment: The `#{user.pollStop}` in the user.xhtml is only evaluated **once** at the time the `p:poll` is rendered. So the behaviour is what is expected.  The closing from the user.java should work though. So you effectively try to do the same from two places. But since you don't call a listener in the poll, I doubt it will also refresh the `stop` attribute. Please do not try to work at to many new things at the same time (looking at your question) and try to get basic things to work first

Comment: And you can do a lot more debugging to investigate. Log the calls to the getter of 'pollStop' (or put a breakpoint and run the app in a debugger) and see when and how often it is called. Very simple basic development skills.